# Java Music File returns "(No such file or directory)" but path seems correct

Tags: java, file-io, audioinputstream

I'm working on a Java game project right now, and I'm trying to import music. However, I can't seem to get it working:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Music {

public static void playSound(String name) {
    try {
        
        System.out.println("music is now playing");
        File file = new File("audio/" + name + ".wav");
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();

        // sleep to allow enough time for the clip to play
        Thread.sleep(10);

        stream.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

The above is my code for my **music.java** class, which is then called in my main **game.java** class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // instantiate this object
    Music.playSound("ahem");
    Game game = new Game();


} // main
```

But my output returns

```
music is now playing 
audio/ahem.wav (No such file or directory)
```

I'm fairly certain that my .wav file is placed in the right spot (in an "audio" folder inside my "bin" folder, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: User `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())` to verify that your relative path really points to your sound file.

Comment: `System.out.println(new File("audio/" + name + ".wav").exists())` <- Remember this will be relative to your programs "working directory"

Comment: System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()) gets /Users/ME/Files/School/MY CLASS' NAME/Java/PROJECT NAME/audio/ahem.wav

Comment: System.out.println(new File("audio/" + name + ".wav").exists()) returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong! I needed to include "bin" before my "audio/" + name + ".wav" path.

i.e., bin/audio/name.wav